# Change Finder sort from descending to ascending in anything but list view?

Tags: finder, sort

Is it possible to change the sort order when viewing files in Finder in the symbol, column or slideshow view?

I am going through pictures and sorting them by creation date. For some reason, the default is that the latest creation date is on top, so descending sort order. When I switch to list view and change it by clicking on the column header, and switch back to any other view, it is the default again.

It seems really strange that this basic option is not possible. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Each View has its own set of options to sort by.
List View is the most comprehensive, followed by Icon. All the others have very limited options.

In effect you can only sort on data you can 'see'. List View has many more options & each option can be sorted ascending or descending by clicking the appropriate header.
Everything else just has a single sort order.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to change the sort order when viewing files in Finder in the symbol, column or slideshow view?
> When I ... switch back to any other view, it is the default again.
> It seems really strange that this basic option is not possible.

Apparently not. I am seeing the same behavior, where it keeps switching back to the default order (ascending), when the list view has been sorted descending by date, or even by name, which would sort image file names in chronologically descending order as well. Nowhere in the View Options is there an option to fix this.